# Creating a correct absolute URL when running ASP.NET MVC application under Visual Studio Windows Azure Emulator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I need to create an absolute URL to specific files in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  I am currently doing this by generating a relative path via `Url.Content` and then using the following extension method to create the absolute path.

```
public static string Absolute(this UrlHelper url, string relativeUrl)
{
    var request = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", 
        (request.IsSecureConnection) ? "https" : "http", 
        request.Url.Host, 
        (request.Url.Port == 80) ? "" : ":" + request.Url.Port, 
        VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativeUrl));
}
```

When running under the Azure Emulator, the proper URL that I need to create is `http://127.0.0.1/myfile.jpg` but when this code executes, the port number comes back as 81 so the URL that is generated is `http://127:0.0.1:81/myfile.jpg`.  However, if I go to `http://127:0.0.1:81/myfile.jpg` it of course doesn't work as the Azure Emulator is listening on port 80, not 81.

I assume this has to do with the built in Azure Emulator/IIS Express load balancer, but I am not sure what change I need to make to my `Url.Absolute` method to return an accurate URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rely on the `Host` header that is being sent by the client:

```
public static string Absolute(this UrlHelper url, string relativeUrl)
{
    var request = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

    return string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
        (request.IsSecureConnection) ? "https" : "http",
        request.Headers["Host"],
        VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativeUrl));
}
```

Comment: Will the host header also include the port number if it exists?  eg. if the application is legitimately deployed at, say, http://www.contoso.com:999/ will the header be "www.contoso.com:999"?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `@Url.Content("~/myfile.jpg");`?  This **converts** a **virtual** (relative) path **to** an application **absolute** path and works finle in IIS,the emulator and when deployed.  See [UrlHelper.Content Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Application-absolute-path is not absolute-path. `/Content/Img/myfile.jpg` != `http://127.0.0.1/Content/Img/myfile.jpg`

Comment: @haim770 is correct.  I need the full absolute path, including the protocol, domain and port.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a summary post that shows all the options here: http://benjii.me/2015/05/get-the-absolute-uri-from-asp-net-mvc-content-or-action/

The quick and simple answer is this:

```
var urlBuilder =
    new System.UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
        {
            Path = Url.Content("~/path/to/anything"),
            Query = null,
        };

string url = urlBuilder.ToString();
```